# How would I set it so the leaderstats stage value doesn't go over the current stage value?

Tags: lua, roblox

I was trying to edit a script with a function for the stage selector buttons, I started with just:

```
event:FireServer("MoveToStage", (CurrentStage (+-) 1) 
player.leaderstats.Stage.Value (+-)= 1
```

and it worked, but I didn't like that it was able to continue adding 1 to the leaderstats stage value, so I tried using `if`,`elseif`,`then` statements to get it to be equal with the current stage and not go over the current stages value. So I'd like to ask if anyone could help me out... I appreciate you in advance.

---

**IMAGE COLOR KEY**

- **RED** = BUTTONS
- ⬜ **WHITE** = LEADERSTATS STAGE VALUE
- **YELLOW** = CURRENT STAGE VALUE & STAGE NAME

[image]

---

**SERVER SCRIPT**

```
-- SERVICES --
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local MarketService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local DataService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")

-- VARIABLES --
local event = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Handler")
local Stages = workspace.Stages

-- DATA STORE --
local PlayerData = DataService:GetDataStore("PlayerData")

-- TABLES --
local ProductID = {
    ["SkipStage"] = 1339405103;
}

-- FUNCTIONS --
function SaveData(player)
    PlayerData:SetAsync(player.UserId, player.leaderstats.Stage.Value)
end

function TpToStage(player, stage)
    if stage == player.CurrentStage.Value then return end
    player.CurrentStage.Value = stage
    player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = Stages[tostring(stage)].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,4,0)
    event:FireClient(player, "UpdateStage", stage)
end

function MoveToStage(player, stage)
    local currentStage = player.leaderstats.Stage

    if stage >= currentStage.Value then stage = currentStage.Value
    elseif stage <= 0 then stage = 0
    elseif stage >= 0 and stage <= currentStage.Value then stage = stage
    end


    TpToStage(player, stage)
end

-- TRIGGERS --
local ProductFunctions = {
    ["P1339405103"] = function(player)
        player.leaderstats.Stage.Value += 1
        TpToStage(player, player.leaderstats.Stage.Value)
    end;
}

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    for i,v in pairs(script.PLAYER:GetChildren()) do
        v:Clone().Parent = player
    end


    local DATA
    pcall(function()
        DATA = PlayerData:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    end)

    if DATA then 
        player.leaderstats.Stage.Value = DATA 
    else 
        player.leaderstats.Stage.Value = 0 
    end

    player.CurrentStage.Value = player.leaderstats.Stage.Value
    event:FireClient(player, "UpdateStage", player.leaderstats.Stage.Value)

    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        task.wait()
        character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame = Stages[tostring(player.leaderstats.Stage.Value)].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,4,0)
    end)
end)

event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, argument1, argument2)
    if argument1 == "SkipStage" then
        if player.leaderstats.Stage.Value < (#(Stages:GetChildren()) - 1) then
            MarketService:PromptProductPurchase(player, ProductID["SkipStage"])
        else
            event:FireClient(player, "MaxStage")
        end

    elseif argument1 == "MoveToStage" then
        MoveToStage(player, tonumber(argument2))
    end
end)

MarketService.ProcessReceipt = function(RecieptInfo)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerByUserId(RecieptInfo.PlayerId)

    if ProductFunctions["P"..RecieptInfo.ProductId] and ProductFunctions["P"..RecieptInfo.ProductId] ~= nil then
        pcall(ProductFunctions["P"..RecieptInfo.ProductId](player), "e")
    end

    return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
end

-- LOOPS --
-- STAGES --
coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
    for i, v in pairs(Stages:GetChildren()) do
        v.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
            if hit and hit.Parent and hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
                local number = tonumber(v.Name)

                if number > player.leaderstats.Stage.Value then
                    player.leaderstats.Stage.Value = number
                    player.CurrentStage.Value = number
                    event:FireClient(player, "UpdateStage", number)
                end
            end
        end)
    end
end))

Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    SaveData(player)
end)

game:BindToClose(function()
    for i, player in pairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
        SaveData(player)
    end
end)
```

---

**CLIENT SCRIPT**

```
task.wait(0.2)

--SERVICES --
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

-- VARIABLES --
local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local CurrentStage = 0
local event = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Handler")
local Stage = script.Parent.Main.EditStageTXT
local SkipButton = script.Parent.Main.SkipStageBTN
local MaxStage = script.Parent.Main.MaxLevelTXT

-- FUNCTIONS -- 
function UpdateStage(number)
    Stage.Text = "Stage: "..tostring(number)
    CurrentStage = number
end

-- TRIGGERS --
SkipButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    event:FireServer("SkipStage")
end)

Stage.LeftEditStageBTN.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(stage)
    event:FireServer("MoveToStage", (CurrentStage - 1))
    player.leaderstats.Stage.Value -= 1
end)

Stage.RightEditStageBTN.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(stage)
    event:FireServer("MoveToStage", (CurrentStage + 1))
    player.leaderstats.Stage.Value += 1
end)

event.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(argument1, argument2)
    if argument1 == "UpdateStage" then
        UpdateStage(tonumber(argument2))
        
    elseif argument1 == "MaxStage" then
        Stage.Visible = false
        SkipButton.Visible = false
        MaxStage.Visible = true
        task.wait(3)
        Stage.Visible = true
        SkipButton.Visible = true
        MaxStage.Visible = false
    end
end)

-- LOOPS --
RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function(player)
    UpdateStage(player.CurrentStage.Value)
end)
```

Was expecting for the script below to do what I wanted it to do, but it decided to stop the whole script from working...

```
Stage.LeftEditStageBTN.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(stage)
    event:FireServer("MoveToStage", (CurrentStage + 1))
    player.leaderstats.Stage.Value += 1

        if stage >= currentStage.Value then stage = currentStage.Value
        elseif stage <= 0 then stage = 0
        elseif stage >= 0 and stage <= currentStage.Value then stage = stage
    end
end)

Stage.RightEditStageBTN.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(stage)
    event:FireServer("MoveToStage", (CurrentStage + 1))
    player.leaderstats.Stage.Value += 1

        if stage >= currentStage.Value then stage = currentStage.Value
        elseif stage <= 0 then stage = 0
        elseif stage >= 0 and stage <= currentStage.Value then stage = stage
    end
end)
```

Comment: I also have an issue when a player resets, it resets the current stage value. Making the stage selector reset to "Stage: 0"

Comment: it looks like you've shared your client code twice and not your server code.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that. Will try and fix it!

Comment: I forgot to explain the 

`event:FireServer("MoveToStage", CurrentStage (+-  1)
player.leaderstats.Stage.Value (+-)= 1
`

The (+-) are just examples to either say like 

`event:FireServer("MoveToStage", CurrentStage + OR -  1)
player.leaderstats.Stage.Value += OR -= 1
`

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm currently boggling my mind.

Comment: Also, I'd like to thank you Kylaaa for cleaning up my mess. I'm kind of new to stackoverflow, this is like my 2nd time using it to ask others for help.

Answer (score 0):

You've provided so much code that it's a bit confusing coming up with an answer. All these other bits that you've included like marketplace products, data stores loading the player's progress, initializing touch events, saving player data, etc.; all of this is unnecessary to your question.

At the most basic, you have two values : `leaderstats.Stage` and `CurrentStage`, and you don't want `CurrentStage` to be able to go beyond `leaderstats.Stage`. The safest thing to do would be to put safety checks into your server Script so that the client cannot request to go higher than their unlocked stage. And the thing is, you've got the right pieces already in place, I think you just need to simplify your code and pass around the right values to make it all work together properly.

Here are the changes I would make...

**Client LocalScript**

- Eliminate the extra variables you use to communicate with the server. Rather than using `local CurrentStage`, use the `player.CurrentStage` value when requesting that the server move you up or down.
- Stop setting the leaderstats values on the client-side. Your RemoteEvent handlers should be in charge of that from the server-side. That way, you can ensure that the server is the source of truth, and the logic is easier to maintain.
- Have your TextLabel that displays the current stage observe the `CurrentStage` and simply update when it changes, that way you don't need to constantly be asking it to update.

```lua
--SERVICES --
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

-- VARIABLES --
local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local event = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Handler")

-- UI Elements
local Stage = script.Parent.Main.EditStageTXT
local SkipButton = script.Parent.Main.SkipStageBTN
local MaxStage = script.Parent.Main.MaxLevelTXT

-- TRIGGERS --
player.CurrentStage.Changed:Connect(function(newValue)
    -- update the text whenever the `CurrentStage` value changes
    Stage.Text = "Stage: " .. tostring(newValue)
end)
SkipButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    event:FireServer("SkipStage")
end)
Stage.LeftEditStageBTN.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(stage)
    -- request the server to move us to the previous stage
    event:FireServer("MoveToStage", player.CurrentStage.Value - 1)
end)
Stage.RightEditStageBTN.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(stage)
    -- request the server to move us to the next stage
    event:FireServer("MoveToStage", player.CurrentStage.Value + 1)
end)
```

**Server Script**

I have only updated these two functions, there were too many other moving parts and I wanted to focus on just the parts that mattered to your problem.

- Since `player.leaderstats.Stage` is the maximum, use that as the upper bounds.
- Update the `MoveToStage` functions logic to reflect that limit.
- Remove the `UpdateStage` clientEvent because the text will be automatically updated when the `CurrentStage.Value` is changed.

```lua
function TpToStage(player, stageNumber)
    if stageNumber == player.CurrentStage.Value then
        return
    end
    player.CurrentStage.Value = stageNumber
    player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = Stages[tostring(stageNumber)].CFrame + Vector3.new(0,4,0)
end

function MoveToStage(player, nextStage)
    -- clamp the value between [0, leaderstats.Stage]
    local function clamp(minimum, value, maximum)
        return math.max(minimum, math.min(value, maximum))
    end
    nextStage = clamp(0, nextStage, player.leaderstats.Stage.Value)

    TpToStage(player, nextStage)
end
```

Comment: You must of read it wrong.

I am not wanting the ```CurrentStage``` to be able to go beyond ```leaderstats.Stage```.
As I don't want the ```leaderstats.Stage``` value to be able to go beyond the ```CurrentStage``` value.

Comment: Btw, this script is from a video. As well as I've just continuously edited small bits to fit my needs. Such as the stage selector buttons ```leaderstats.Stage.Value = CurrentStage.Value```